# Value of string magically changes after function is used on a different string

Tags: c, dbg

[image]

As shown in this dbg debug log, `string1 = '0' <repeats 28 times>, "1000"` is printed after the intToBinary(num1, string1) function call. But then on the next instruction intToBinary(num2, string2) is called. As you can see **different** parameters are passed to the intToBinary function. How come the variable `string1` is affected by the second time the function is called using **different** variables? In the log it says the first character changes from 0 to `\` (or `\0`?).

Here's the pastebin of the function in case necessary. http://pastebin.com/EsQNMjej

```
void intToBinary(int num, char* string)
{
    string[32] = '\0';
    int i,j;
    int temp = num;

    // is num negative?
    int isNegative = num < 0 ? 1 : 0;

    //negate all bits and add 1 (two complements)
    if(isNegative)
    {
        temp = -1 * temp; //absolute value

        //In order to get the negative number in
        // 2's complement you can either negate and
        // increment, or decrement by 1 and negate.
        //In this function, temp gets negated after
        //the conversion to string
        --temp;
    }

    //Write binary of positive num to string
    for(i = 0, j = 31; i < 32; i++,j--)
    {
        if(pow(2,j) <= temp)
        {
           //Temp is decreased when the bit is 1
           temp = temp - pow(2, j);
           string[i] = '1';
        }
        else
        {
            //Nothing happens to temp when the bit is 0
            string[i] = '0';
        }
    }

    if(isNegative)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            //negate bits
            string[i] = string[i] == '1' ? '0' : '1';
        }
    }
}
```

I just don't get what's going on here. I tried switching the order of the two function calls, so it got changed to the following

```
intToBinary(num2, string2);
intToBinary(num1, string1);
```

And magically, the first byte stays `'0'`, which is what I want. But now I just want to know why this changed in the first place...

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Use the debugger (`gdb`) and set *watchpoints* (with the `watch` command of `gdb`)

Comment: You probably should read a lot more about C programming and understand what is [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string[32] = '\0';`

That overflows your input buffer. And I think you'll find that your `string1` is immediately after `string2` in memory. So overflowing `string2` by 1 byte will run into `string1`.

Comment: So what should it be instead? Should I even be assigning the null terminator?

Comment: If you want a string then of course you must NUL terminate. Just make your string buffers 33 instead of 32 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to store a 32-bit binary number in 32 bytes; you forgot to allocate an extra byte for the null terminator.  When the null is written after `string2`, it clobbers the start of `string1`.

Undefined behaviour (writing beyond the end of an array) leads to undefined results.